# Is there any way to expand the Processes pane in Sql Server 2008 Activity Monitor?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

This should possibly be a Microsoft support question, but does anyone know if there's a way to expand the Processes (or any of the other panes) in SSMS 2008 Activity Monitor?

All i actually want to see is a list of running processes, but even if i collapse all the other panes i can't expand one to fit the screen.  It seems like such a simple thing i can't believe it's not possible!

Does anyone have any solutions or, failing that, any suggestions of a workaround?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No way to resize that I'm aware of; 2 partial workarounds:

- Set the sorting or filtering so the
  things of interest will be on top,
  i.e. by database name, or application
  name.
- use exec sp_who2 in a query window

I think the activity monitor is a work in process, we're supposed to be excited about being able to launch profiler directly from it, and love all the pretty graphs, when all we really want is to be able to resize a window.

Comment: And here I am, ten years later, still unable to resize a window.